# FadeIn() effect stops working after widget has completed a full cycle, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a random problem...after this widget rotates a complete/full cycle the fadeIn() effect stops work?

Here is my HTML & CSS

```
.new-tweet { opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
#in-auction-cycle-content { overflow:hidden; width:275px; height:102px; list-style-type:none; margin-bottom:6px; }

                <ul id="in-auction-cycle-content">
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;1</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;2</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;3</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;4</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;5</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;6</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;7</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;8</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;9</span></li>
                 <li><span class="in-auction-reg">KH52 YBN</span> <span class="in-auction-highest-bid">&pound;10</span></li>
                </ul>
```

Here is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function tweet(){
  $("#in-auction-cycle-content li:last").hide().addClass('new-tweet').prependTo("#in-auction-cycle-content").slideDown(300);
  $('.new-tweet').animate({opacity: '1'}, function(){$(this).removeClass('new-tweet')});
 };
 setInterval(tweet,3600);
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: JUST SOLVED IT! $(document).ready(function(){
 function tweet(){
  $("#in-auction-cycle-content li:last").hide().addClass('new-tweet').prependTo("#in-auction-cycle-content").slideDown(300);
  $('.new-tweet').css({'opacity':'0', 'filter':'alpha(opacity=0)'}).animate({opacity: '1'}, function(){$(this).removeClass('new-tweet')});
 };
 setInterval(tweet,3600);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding {opacity: '1'} explicitly, but not removing it. Just removing the class wouldn't do the trick. I suggest you either add a class old-tweet that has opacity 1, or remove it explicitly after